# ICM 2014 streaming video

Tags: soft-question, icm-2014

Is there a possibility to watch ICM 2014 opening ceremony and the big talks online?

I hope there is since it was possible for the previous meeting.

Comment: Maybe this link works: http://www.icm2014.org/en/vod/vod

Comment: Or perhaps: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCN9aHvmDNzpXuWR5XmOIz5A

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps a bit late at this point, but the opening ceremony is being broadcast live on http://www.ebs.co.kr/onair?channelCodeString=tv , with the caveat that so far there's been Korean translations over top of the English from the actual speakers.

I think the talks will be uploaded to the ICM's Youtube account later on, as well: https://www.youtube.com/user/ICM2014VOD

Comment: Thanks! It is great that sometimes they have only subtitles.